# Does Jagacy have to be launched from within the target app

Tags: legacy, 3270, legacy-app

We have a target CSharp app which needs to be populated with the data from a 3270 terminal. We intend to use Jagacy3270 as the terminal emulator for it and also utilize the screen scraping functionality in order to populate the fields of the CSharp application.

1. Can the Jagacy app be a separate process (that is instantiated separately) and still communicate with the target CSharp application ? If so, how would we go about doing this? OR
2. Does the Jagacy app have to be launched from within the target CSharp application in order for them to be able to communicate ? How would we be able to launch the Jagacy application from within our CSharp application? Would it be simply invoking the Jagacy Jar file(assuming all the correct dependencies are met)